# display page title in DNN Skin

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning

i want to use the active "tab"-name or page name inside my DNN Skin.

I can't find anything on the web about it (which is slightly odd). I'm looking for a control or sth. which i could use inside my ascx-file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think that there is a built-in skin object for displaying the name of the page.  You can use this snippet in your skin to get the page's name:

```
<%= Server.HtmlEncode(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName) %>
```

You can also get the page's title (the text displayed in the browser window title) via

```
<%= Server.HtmlEncode(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Title) %>
```

Comment: I confused the terminology.. i wanted to know how to display the Page Title instead of the page name.. but thanks though - helped in any way! do you know that as well?

Comment: Peter have yu able to display page title?
I were trying to display page title instead of page name in the menu but doesn't succeed